# With Node.js, does it make sense to stick all of the error handling into the mechanism intended for all uncaught exceptions?

Tags: node.js, error-handling

It seems that node.js uses some kind of a threading model to execute what it calls "aynch" code.  The trouble with this is I can't catch exceptions that are happening externally in another call stack, so they bubble up to the main thread execution and are caught by a handler.

Does it make sense to stick all of the error handling into the mechanism intended for all uncaught exceptions and stop trying to try/catch in more granular places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be problems doing this. Have a look at: [node.js - Dealing with uncaught exceptions](http://debuggable.com/posts/node-js-dealing-with-uncaught-exceptions:4c933d54-1428-443c-928d-4e1ecbdd56cb)

Comment: So, essentially there's no good way to deal with this? Is it possible to override whatever class is being used to house the external threads to wrap a try/catch/finally around the entire thing in the event that I have a process that absolutely MUST be cleaned up after?